# Integral of cdf of a symmetric random variable

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

How to compute $$\int_{-k}^{k}F(x)dx$$
where $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of continuous random variable $X$  which has symmetric pdf about $x=0$ and $k>0$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Firebug what is the answer of the integral?

Comment: @ChristophHanck This question is from a reference book. So, there is nothing wrong with this question.

Comment: One would be permitted to doubt that it's from a reference book, because such books provide *answers,* not questions.  This reads like a textbook or quiz question and it has a simple answer (depending on $k$ but not on $F$) you can literally see by plotting the graph of $F.$

Comment: As whuber suggests, it's obvious by inspection. If $F$ is a continuous cdf that's symmetric about 0, the answer is immediate. If it's not obvious, draw a picture and (if you do it correctly) the answer should then be obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially translating whuber's comment into analysis and using point symmetry of the cdf around $(0,1/2)$, $F(k)=1-F(-k)$ or $F(-k)=1-F(k)$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{-k}^{k}F(x)dx&=\int_{-k}^{0}F(x)dx+\int_{0}^{k}F(x)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{k}[1-F(x)]dx+\int_{0}^{k}F(x)dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{k}1dx\\
&=k
\end{align*}
$$
Two examples:

```
k <- 1

> integrate(pnorm, -k, k)$value
[1] 1

> integrate(punif, -k, k, min=-4,max=4)$value
[1] 1
```

My initial, more clumsy solution:

Also by symmetry a, say, convex part of the cdf between $-k$ and 0 will be offset by a concave part between 0 and $k$ (the areas between the red and lightblue line in the plot below are equal), such that the integral is equal to a trapezoid on $-k$ and $k$ with rectangle height $1-F(k)$ and a triangle with height $F(k)-(1-F(k))=2F(k)-1$. All in all, the area is
$$
2k(1-F(k))+2k\frac{2F(k)-1}{2}=k
$$

Schematically:
[image]

```
stddev <- .75
x <- seq(-2, 2,by=0.01)
plot(x, pnorm(x, sd=stddev), type="l", lwd=2, col="lightblue")

segments(k, 0, k, pnorm(k, sd=stddev),lty=2)
segments(-k, 0, -k, 1-pnorm(k, sd=stddev),lty=2)
segments(-k, 1-pnorm(k, sd=stddev), k, pnorm(k, sd=stddev), lty=1, lwd=2, col="red")
abline(v=0, lty=2)
segments(-k, 1-pnorm(k, sd=stddev), k, 1-pnorm(k, sd=stddev),lty=2)
segments(0, pnorm(k, sd=stddev), k, pnorm(k, sd=stddev),lty=2)
text(-0.1, pnorm(k, sd=stddev), "F(k)")
text(-k-.25, 1-pnorm(k, sd=stddev), "1-F(k)")
```

Comment: +1. But everything goes from *clear* to *obvious* when you cut the picture into two pieces along the graph of $F$ bordered at right and left by $\pm k:$ rotate and shift one piece and place it on top of the other to obtain a rectangle of width $k$ and height $1.$

Answer (score 5):

Words are superfluous:

[image: Well, unless you're visually impaired or can't see the image for some other reason... in which case, this is a drawing of a symmetric F with the area corresponding to the integral marked in one colour - light purple, and the remainder of the box (-k<x<k) times (0<y<1) in another colour - sort of buff. The upper shape is simply a rotation of the lower purple shape; they're the same area, each making up half that box]

... but sadly I need more than 22 characters.